# Python to executable via py2exe -- how can I enable input as well?

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

I know how to create an executable out of a python script and I can also run it. But I don't know how to call my functions, for example. I'd like to be able to do that from the same command prompt that I launch the executable.

Comment: It's not very clear what your asking. What do you mean "call my functions?"

Comment: @JoelCornett When I run my program as an executable, I want my functions to be callable just like in a regular Python script. All I can do is run the program, define the functions, but there's no way I can do calculate_cosine() or anything like that.

Comment: @user1614466 That's not what py2exe does. Maybe you also want to distribute your program as a package so that it can be used with `import`. See [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Comment: If you want the functions in your module to be callable, then why are you packaging them in an executable?

Comment: Also, I don't see how the title of your question has anything to do with what you're asking.

Comment: @aneroid Oh ok thanks. Can I run the python script from the Windows command prompt and call the functions that way?

Comment: @JoelCornett sorry, I don't fully understand how this works.

Comment: @user1614466 Not sure what you're trying to do. To be able to do what you describe, use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) or `sys` and `argv[0]` etc. to call different functions when executing the .exe from the command line. Otherwise, see @Aesthete's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I *think* I understand what you're trying to do. Let say you have a script:

```
# module named test.py
def bar():
  print 'bar!'

def foo():
  print 'foo!'
```

And you want to call `bar` or `foo` from the command line.

```
> python -c "from test import *; bar(); foo();"
```

This should output the following:

```
> bar!
> foo!
```

The `-c` option specifies a **command**. Note this this will only work when you type this into the console when you're **in the same directory** as your `test` script.